# Codeigniter activerecord OR select statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using the latest version of codeigniter and am trying to write a simple query using the activerecord class, but can't quite figure out how to do an OR statement. Here's the code:

```
function get_active_trades()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('trades', array('trade_status !=' => 2));

    return $query->result();
}
```

Ideally, it should be if trade_status != 2 or user_trade_status != 2. However, I can't seem to find a way to make this happen. I've found the following on the help page, but can't seem to get it to work either:

```
$this->db->or_where();
```

Any suggestions on how this should be done with activerecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
function get_active_trades() {
     $this->db->where('trade_status <>', 2);
     $this->db->or_where('user_trade_status <>', 2);
     return $this->db->get('trades')->result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. Will accept this answer when it's available.